# Private and Unknown MAC Addresses

Tags: windows-10, networking, mac, ip-address, private-network

I scan my network using Avast Virus protection, usually once a day. I noticed that a "connected device" shows up and I can't figure out what it is. All my devices are accounted for. The MAC address that shows up is F4:B8:5E:7A:9C:60 and when I look it up it just says Texas Instruments and nothing more. Could someone tell me what it is? Or how I can find out what it is? Also, from time to time, another device shows up as "generic computer". Its MAC address is 40:25:C2:C4:62:88?

Comment: 40:25:C2 is Intel. TI and Intel both make networking chips (Ethernet controllers, Wi-Fi controllers). Some product manufacturers don't get an IEEE OUI (a prefixed range of MAC addresses assigned to a single vendor) for themselves, and instead have their chipset vendor program the MAC addresses from the chipset vendor's OUI. These could both be IoT devices you forgot to account for, like maybe a smart TV or an off-brand smart thermostat.

Comment: What kind of network hardware are you using? If it's managed you might be able to track the AP or switch port for this specific MAC address.

Answer (score 1):

Try a utility that provides more information, such as Nirsoft's [Wireless Network Watcher](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_network_watcher.html), shown below.

[image: Wireless Network Watcher]

Knowing the device information, name, adapter type and detection dates may help track it down. Perhaps a camera?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see the associated IP addresses using the arp command on your computer, or (better) by logging in to the web interface of your router. Once you have the IP addresses you could use a port scanner like nmap to check if those devices have any open ports. Usually you can make an educated guess about the device type by looking at the detected ports.

It's possible that they already have ports 80/443 open, thus are running some kind of webserver. Typing the IP address in your browser eg http(s)://1.1.1.1 **may** work for some devices. It could be your router, printer, television set or another Internet appliance. You smart phone perhaps. Some devices may be connected with an ethernet cable, others may be connected to the wifi and it's very possible they don't show up all the time because they shut down or enter sleep state at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all one subnet, Advanced IP Scanner (Famatech) is an excellent tool to see devices, IP address, and device MAC address, and often device name.

I recommend this small, free app to you.

Since it shows all connected IP addresses, it will help you find unidentified (unapproved) devices.

Answer (score 0):

Log into your router, change your Wifi password, reboot your router, and see if the MAC addresses are visible on the network.

You may have had rogue devices on your network.  To prevent this:

- Factory reset your router.  Then log into it, and ensure your router has the latest firmware update applied.
- Go through your router's settings and disable any cloud or other services you don't need, such as Universal Plug and Play, network shares, FTP, media servers, etc.
- Ensure your Wifi passwords are not easy to guess, and make sure they are set to use WPA2 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research in this website:https://maclookup.app/search?
I found that this two MAC addresses you detected belongs to:Intel Corporate(40:25:C2:C4:62:88) & Texas Instruments(F4:B8:5E:7A:9C:60).
If some of your devices use the accessories from these two companies, it could be the cause of you being able to detect these two MAC addresses.